# Why can't i see /Users/Evalyn/folder13/trydjango/src

Tags: django

```
Evalyns-iMac:trydjango Evalyn$ pwd
/Users/Evalyn/folder13/trydjango
Evalyns-iMac:trydjango Evalyn$ ls
bin     lib     pyvenv.cfg  src
Evalyns-iMac:trydjango Evalyn$ pwd
/Users/Evalyn/folder13/trydjango
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` shows present working directory. It will show the current directory path.
You need to change directory to src.

```
cd /Users/Evalyn/folder13/trydjango/src
```

Then you can do `pwd` and will get it.